# Unable to create a formatted JSON file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a newbie in python (Using python 2.7) and I am trying to write a JSON file like this

```
import os;
import json;

BUILDNUMBER = "1.0.0"

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
       self.buildNumber = BUILDNUMBER;

foo = Foo()
s = json.dumps(foo.__dict__) 
os.system("echo {0} > ./build.json".format(s));
```

The contents of build.json looks like this

{buildNumber: 1.0.0}

I want it to look like this

{"buildNumber" : "1.0.0"}

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How about just using `open` to open the file for writing... and then `json.dump()` (no s!) to it. Or otherwise hope that no one decides to use `\`something evil\`` as the build number...

Comment: While you're still new to Python, you should move to Python 3 ASAP because Python 2.x will become deprecated in 2020

Comment: This is some infra stuff that I do not have a handle to or control over at work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not use `os.system` to call `echo` to redirect to a file. Never. In Python. Like ever.

Since no one showed how to do it right, this is how you write a JSON file in Python:

```
with open('./build.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(foo.__dict__, f)
```